# How do I specify the dockerfile stage in Visual Studio Code Remote?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile. I want to configure VS Code Remote to build the dev stage of the Dockerfile rather than the last stage in the Dockerfile.

I'm pretty sure this configuration would go in the .devcontainer.json file. I've read through the .devcontainer.json reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_devcontainerjson-reference and tried `runArgs`, but these are the run-time args, not the build args.

I tried this:

```js
{
        "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
        "extensions": ["ms-python.python"],
        "runArgs": [
                "--target",
                "dev"
        ]
}
```

and:

```js
{
        "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
        "extensions": ["ms-python.python"],
        "buildArgs": [
                "--target",
                "dev"
        ]
}
```

When I used `runArgs`, I got `Failed: Starting the development container` because `target` is not a `docker run` option. When I tried `buildArgs`, the argument was apparently ignored, which makes sense since it isn't listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

runArgs specifies the arguments to use with the "docker run" command.
In this case, we need to pass arguments to the "docker build" command.

For specifying build arguments, you need to use the "build" property. In your example, you would need your devcontainer.json file to contain:

```js
"build": { 
    "target": "dev" 
},
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for before. I don't know if I missed it or if this is a new parameter that has been added. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dev Container: Existing Docker Compose mode.
docker-compose service can specified Dockerfile stage.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround.

I can manually build the Dockerfile myself:

```
docker build --target dev -t vizd .
```

and then use the `image` parameter in `.devcontainer.json`:

```js
{
    "image": "vizd",
    "extensions": ["ms-python.python"]
}
```

Not perfect, but doable.